# What's the most popular Namecoin exchange?

Tags: exchanges, namecoin

There are several Namecoin [exchanges listed at official wiki](http://dot-bit.org/Trade) and [Bitparking](https://exchange.bitparking.com/main/) seems to be the oldest, but which one is the most used?

Comment: Namecoins have such a low value you shouldn't really care, just pick one.

Comment: @Lohoris, value doesn't really matter to me. Exchange popularity does.

Comment: I'm sorry, but Namecoin is so popular you got 0 answers so far, so...

Comment: I couldn't find actual numbers (so I'm not going to formally answer), but Bitparking, in what open buy/sell prices and volumes are listed on the site, is by far the largest.

Comment: @Lohoris obviously. :)

Comment: @BinaryMage thanks, that's something to begin with!

Comment: This answer has been attracting a lot of low-quality answers and is off-topic by community guidelines. Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Almost everyone seems to use the [Bitparking Namecoin Exchange](https://exchange.bitparking.com/main).

Comment: I don't disagree, but can you back that up with numbers? "Almost everyone" is far from absolute.

Answer (score 0):

bitparking is not recommended as they don't know what the word BACKUP is and is holding people coin now because their HD crashed and have not fixed the issue.  I highly recommend you stay away from them.

There are so many other alt coin exchanges out there.

I am currently using:

http://cryptsy.com/

Comment: It seems that since I asked this question BTC-E has taken the lead in terms of Namecoin traffic - but this is just my educated guess, haven't got the numbers to back it up.

Comment: I love how someone down voted my bash on bitparking.. go to their website and see for yourself:
2013-11-26: Work on the recovery site got delayed but it's back in progress
            and I hope to have something up soon. I have been processing
            recoveries during this time so some funds have been restored.


Yet I still have not received my lost coin there despite multiple attempt to get it back.. and we are only talking about 3 NMC.  LoLz.. what a looooooooser website

Comment: currently 94+ BTC and 69k+ NMC not returned to customers.
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=165153.msg5689939#msg5689939

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bitdango market search to find Namecoin markets:

http://bitdango.com/markets?baseCurrencies=NMC

Then look at each market's order book, more orders means more liquidity (probably) so that's one way to base your decision.

Answer (score -1):

www.cryptsy.com, www.mintpal.com, www.coinmkt.com

Comment: While listing exchanges that list namecoin may be useful, you are not necessarily answering the question which is the most popular, maybe check the relative volumes of these exchanges and add it to your answer.